# How to configure gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab

How does one configure a `gitlab-runner`. I'm drowning in the documentation on GitLab. I can't seem to find the correct documentation to state this.

I'd like to for example set the executer for the runner.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is in your current configuration, what isn't working? For documentation on the different executors see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html.

Comment: @SethosII Thanks! You just answered my question, post an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For documentation on the different executors see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html.